# manipulate textures in real time using GPU

Tags: java, textures, assets, jmonkeyengine, realtime

I'm looking for some way (tutorial, library or build in option) to draw texture on JMonkey in real time. So I have 2 images one a normal texture that is fairly big(4000x4000) and another much smaller texture (100x100) the second texture is white(or we can set alpha high) with something drawn on it (say a tree) now I would like said drawing (tree) to be drawn on the bigger texture in such a way that it does not massively slow down the system and that it easily ignores the unused pixels.

I already know I can use a for loop to change each value of a texture but that is a CPU computation I would much rather, if possible, offload this to the GPU.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? If you want to render some sort of terrain with trees you can simply draw quads textured with your smaller images.

Comment: Look into render to texture techniques, or rendertargets.